# wordpress get data from custom table call to ajax error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get data from custom table when button click with jquery and ajax but i got error
how to solve this.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\getwp\wp-content\plugins\getwp_P\display.php on
>   line 3

My jquery is here

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
> $("#display").click(function() {          
>   $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
>     type: "GET",
>     url: "display.php",                   
>     dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
>     success: function(response){                    
>         $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
>         //alert(response);
>     }
>
> }); }); });
> ```

display.php is here

> get_results("SELECT * from
>   `wp_school_post`"); 
>   echo ""; echo "ID"; foreach ($rows as $row )
>   {   echo
>   "";   echo "$row->postid";   echo "";
>   } 
>   echo
>   ""; ?>

html button

```
<input type="button" id="display" class="button" value="Fetch All Data" onClick="fetch_data();" /> 

<div id="responsecontainer" align="center">
```

any solution

Answer (score 0):

on top of display.php include 
 **wp-config.php**
 or
 **wp-load.php**.

Comment: include or require ?? wp-config.php